# Class that represents parts of another object?

Tags: vb.net

I have a class called "EntryData" with a couple of fields in it, "name", "entrydate", "enteredby" and "key" a foreign key. The key points to the "DataEntered" class with "key", "startdate", "enddate" and "values", an array of doubles. This matched the layout of a db we were using, which stored data in two tables.

Now we are adapting this to a db that stores all the same data, but in a single table. We would like the API to remain the same.

So, I hope this makes sense:

Can I make a new class called "DataEntered" that has no instances its own, and consists solely of pointers to particular fields in "EntryData"? That is, there would be no *objects* of this class, it would simply be a sort of wrapper that always referred to the underlying EntryData it was called on, like this…

```
myEntryDataInstance.DataEntered.startdate
```

In this case there is no instance of DataEntered.

The easy way to solve my problem would be if I could put periods in my method names, but that doesn't seem to work. :-)

Comment: Why can't you just use the same original `DataEntered` class for both data access objects?  I must be missing something.

Comment: I struggling with"no object int his class" and "no instance of this class." Not sure what you mean. But it sounds sort of like you asking if you can have a new class that act as a "wrapper" for both existing classes and the answer is yes. You can do it using composition such that you new class has an ref to an object of each existing class.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting question, but I can't quite understand it from what you've written... Can you please try and elaborate?

Comment: Ahhh, Karl, I think you may have hit on the right attack. Instead of making one class that is "part of the other", I think I should instead make a new class that contains both. Then the "mini class" with the and the "maxi class" can both point to the same underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

What your asking for is called inheritance but VB does not allow you to inherit from multiple classes.  You would have to inherit from one class and then write in pointers to the second class which would have to be saved as a variable in your class.

Problem is, what do you plan to do with this? Are you using the Entity Framework or your own homebrewed data manager? If you are using something gereric, it won't know how to handle you NEW class with multiple tables.

Comment: It's homegrown, and has accessor methods to the underlying data. To be specific, the data is initially loaded from the DB into generic tables. We found this was *by far* the fastest and easiest way to talk to multiple similar sources.

Comment: I dont use the MS stuff either, I find it slower than what I can do and it limits you in so many ways. Great for playing/learning and small apps but nothing I would use in my apps.